# Perl server client issue (buffer not flush)

Tags: perl

I do have below client and server written in perl. Issue is client never properly send and receive message from server. 
requirement is to send a message to server and get the response from server and based on that take the decision. I have write a server client test classes with STDOUT and STDIN and those working fine. I think that because I press ENTER after every send command.

Client

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $rhostname='192.168.0.181';
my $hostname="support";
my $port='7071';
my $script_log_dir="/var/sdplog/support";

use IO::Socket; 
use strict;

$| = 1;  
my $host_ip='0.0.0.0';
my $host_port='7088';
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET ( 
    PeerAddr => $rhostname, 
    PeerPort => $port,
    Proto => 'tcp', 
   ); 
   die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock; 
   $sock->autoflush(1);

   my $query = "START:192.168.0.20:3:1:1:".$host_ip.":".$host_port;

   my $count=0;

   print "sending $query\n";
   print $sock "$query";

   my $data = <$sock>;
   print $data;
   close($sock);
```

Server -  code

```
while ($q != -999){
    $logger->debug('waiting for socket....');
    my $new_sock = $sock->accept();
#       sleep(5);
    $i++;   
    $logger->debug($i.' accept');
    while(<$new_sock>) {

    #       print $_;
            $logger->debug("received command - ".$_);
            my $ip_status = 2;

            @input_command = split(':', $_);

            $command = @input_command[0];
            $server_ip = @input_command[1];
            $retry_count= @input_command[2];
            $wait_time = @input_command[3];
            $next_ping_wait = @input_command[4];
            $client_ip = @input_command[5];
            $client_port = @input_command[6];

            @ping_array=($server_ip,$retry_count,$wait_time,$next_ping_wait);
            $logger->debug("received request ".@input_command);
            $logger->debug($command);
            if ($command eq "START"){
                    $logger->debug($command." received. checking server status");
                    $ip_status = network->ping_ip(@ping_array);
                    $logger->debug("ping status - ".$ip_status);
#                       $logger->debug($client_ip.$client_port);
    #               send_message($client_ip,$client_port,$ip_status); # do some 
                    sleep(2);
                    print $new_sock "$ip_status\n";

            }else{

                    $logger->debug($command." received");          }
            }
}

close($sock);
exit 0;
```

Server is in listening state. When I run the client below is the output.

```
>perl client.pl 
sending START:192.168.0.20:3:1:1:0.0.0.0:7088
```

On server

```
2012/08/21 18:49:04 DEBUG> server.pl:89 main:: - waiting for socket....
2012/08/21 18:49:08 DEBUG> server.pl:93 main:: - 1 accept
```

But thats all. Once I clicked CTRL+C client terminate and rest of the logs on server print as expected. Seems not flushing to read from server.

```
2012/08/21 18:56:05 DEBUG> server.pl:97 main:: - received command -   START:192.168.0.20:3:1:1:0.0.0.0:7088
2012/08/21 18:56:05 DEBUG> server.pl:113 main:: - received request 7
2012/08/21 18:56:05 DEBUG> server.pl:114 main:: - START
2012/08/21 18:56:05 DEBUG> server.pl:116 main:: - START received. checking server  status
2012/08/21 18:56:05 DEBUG> network.pm:31 network::ping_ip - 192.168.0.20 is alive
2012/08/21 18:56:05 DEBUG> server.pl:118 main:: - ping status - 1
2012/08/21 18:56:07 DEBUG> server.pl:89 main:: - waiting for socket....
```

But wasn't able to find a solution. Please shed some light as I am stuck in this for few hours now.

Answer (score 2):

You server is waiting for EOF or newline symbol, but in client doesn't send it.
When you terminate client, server receives EOF, server stop's reading from `$new_sock` and all other code work as expected.

You should add newline symbol to `$query` in `client`

```
-print $sock "$query";
+print $sock $query."\n";
```

And `chomp` for received data in `server`

```
while(<$new_sock>) {
+    chomp;
```